# How to get CURLs reponse in Array

Tags: php, curl

I have one problem regarding CURL.
I am trying send CURL request to http://whatismyipaddress.com

so..
is there any way to get curl response in array ?
because right now it display the HTML Page but i want the response in array.

here is my code...

```
$ipAdd = '121.101.152.170';
$ch = curl_init("http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/".$ipAdd);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);      
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

So.. currently i am getting the detail HTML page but i want the out put as array or XML.

Comment: What do you want in this array or xml? Currently, a split on "\n" can help you.

Comment: As noted by Col. Shrapnel, this is against the WhatIsMyIPAddress.com [terms of use](http://whatismyipaddress.com/terms-of-use) unless you have prior written permission.

Answer (score 3):

The "easiest" path is going to be to find the surrounding text & extract based on that.

If you're willing to step your dedication to this up, you can use something like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ & go from there.

**edit:** actually you can use this (it is built into php5)  - http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php 
more specifically, this - http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php